# PHP generating JSON with multiple arrays

Tags: php, json

i want to generate json in this format

```
{
    "name": "item1",
    "description": "mydescript1"

}, 
{
    "name": "item2",
    "description": "mydescript2"

}
```

i have done this so far

```
for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($name_); $i++){
    $ToSend_Json["name"]  = $name_[$i];
    $ToSend_Json["description"]  = $description_[$i];


}
 echo (json_encode($ToSend_Json));
```

the output i get for this is the last json which in this case is

```
 {
    "name": "item2",
    "description": "mydescript2"

}
```

what will be the correct way to do this

Comment: `$ToSend_Json[$i]["name"]  = $name_[$i]; $ToSend_Json[$i]["description"]  = $description_[$i];`

Comment: That json is invalid as it has more then one top level node and no array around them `[{...},{...}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the values at each iteration of the loop. You should use an array for each iteration.

```
$json_array = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_); $i++){
    $ToSend_Json["name"] = $name_[$i];
    $ToSend_Json["description"] = $description_[$i];
    $json_array[] = $ToSend_Json;
}

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Alternatively, you could use a foreach which is a better method for iterating a loop:

```
$json_array = [];

foreach ($name_ as $i => $name) {
    $ToSend_Json["name"] = $name;
    $ToSend_Json["description"] = $description_[$i];
    $json_array[] = $ToSend_Json;
}

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Comment: Array Push is a pointless, useless legacy function.  All you need is `$json_array[] = $ToSend_Json;` - ie. no function calls.

Comment: There are also little point in the `(json_encode($json_array))`  extra `(....)` too.  lol... sorry.  It's ok, just ugly to me... haha

Comment: id suggest a foreach too;p

Comment: Or at least `count` instead of `sizeof` ... another function that needs to be removed.  But `foreach($name_ as $i => $value)` then remove  `$ToSend_Json["name"]  = $value;` is much cleaner.  In fact I wouldn't mind seeing how `$name_` and `$description_` are built there is likely some things there that could be better.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestion @LawrenceCherone I've added it.

Comment: No problem, glad you took my advice. It's perfect now!